# How to change a thickness of a hrule?

Tags: rules, report

I am searched for changing a thickness of a `\hrule` in my report document ? any idea?

Comment: the latex syntax is `\rule` not `\hrule` but if you want to use `\hrule` then `\hrule height 2cm` should work. The latex syntax would be `\rule{\texwidth}{2cm}`

Comment: Thaank's it's working now (y)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, typo: `\textwidth`

Comment: @YounessGI, don't forget to use `\noindent` before the rule to pull it to the left margin.

Comment: @Sigur if you use `\rule`, not `\hrule`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The latex syntax is `\rule` not `\hrule` but if you want to use `\hrule` then

```
\hrule height 2cm
```

should work. The latex syntax would be

```
\begin{center}
\rule{\textwidth}{2cm}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Wow, the parametrisation of `\hrule` is quite uncommon, I expected something like `\hrule[height=2cm]` or so. But surprisingly it worked.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica [] optional arguments are a latex macro syntax, no tex primitives use square brackets in such a way. (Nor should the primitives appear in latex documents)

Comment: `\rule` and `\hrule` are not identical though, is that right?  In particular, `hrule` does not introduce vertical space whereas `rule` does.

Comment: @jII they are completely different `\hrule`is a latex-defined horizontal mode command, `\hrule` is a tex primitve veritical mode command. `\rule`does not produce vertical space but like a letter such as `x` will start a paragraph if used in vmode, and a paragraph start may introduce space.

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
\begin{center}
\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
\end{center}
```

is what most users would want..

Comment: titletoc doesn't like it though, it somehow indents the line; no problem with hrule